# ffmpeg specify order of applied filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video that I want to first crop, then scale and output the result as images. I've looked around [in](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) [the](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide) docs but couldn't find a definite answer as to in what order ffmpeg applies its filters.
Currently, I'm running

```
ffmpeg -i vid -filter:v "crop={0}:{1}:{2}:{3}".format(str(width), str(height), str(x_min), str(y_min)) -c:a copy -crf 23 crop_vid
```

Followed by

```
ffmpeg -i crop_vid -vf 'scale={0}*iw:{0}*ih'.format(str(resize_factor)) -c:a copy -crf 23 os.path.join(img_path, '%04d.bmp')
```

I'm running these as subprocesses from a python script, hence the partial python notation. Could I somehow run this as one script ensuring the order of first crop, then scale instead of running ffmpeg twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you need to specify the filters in the required order, separated by a comma.

So `-filter:v "crop=W:H:X:Y,scale=W:H"`

Comment: Thanks for the input! Do you happen to know what the difference is in using `-filter:v` versus `-vf` ?

Comment: `-vf` wll be applied to all video streams for that output file. Same is true for `-filter:v`, however it can be narrowed by adding  stream index i.e. `-filter:v:2`. So the filters are only applied to the third video output stream. This can't be done with `-vf` which is an older syntax.